# ThreadLocal source code Confusion

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ThreadLocal<String> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<String>();
        threadLocal.set("String1");
        threadLocal.set("String2");
        threadLocal.set("String3");

        System.out.println("==============");
        System.out.println("++ " + threadLocal.get());
        System.out.println("++ " + threadLocal.get());
    }
}


the output is 
============= 
++ String3 
++ String3
```

see the set method in the source code, for specified Thread,its threadlocalmap can only hold on one map entry? as the sample shows, map.set(this, value); here "this" is the var "threadLocal", so "String3" will override the previous value.
Do I mistake this?

```
public void set(T value) {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        ThreadLocalMap map = getMap(t);
        if (map != null)
            map.set(this, value);// here "this" is the var "threadLocal"
        else
            createMap(t, value);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, `ThreadLocal` can only hold one value at a time.

Comment: Also you can read the 'ThreadLocal' documentation in order to clarify your doubts and see the 'set(T value)' method definition.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThreadLocal is a local member/variable of the current thread; so each thread gets exactly one value.

At the same time there is no restriction on the type of value being set, in your example you are setting it as String, same way this can be an instance of the class, collection.

When you want all the values to be available from your code then  put them together in a collection(list), or a custom type which collects all the values that you want.

Answer (score 1):

`ThreadLocal` maps from Thread to value. When asking from the same thread - so with the same key - the returned value is of course the same.

This is the purpose of ThreadLocal: to deliver always the same value to a thread.